# How to use loopj get in Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, loopj

I am trying to use json http request with Widget but nothing happens just a message on console as

> D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 366K, 5% free 10713K/11207K, paused 5ms+30ms
>   V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 183 from 121 (151%)

See bellow the code

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        String number = getCurrentPrice();
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.bitcoin_widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, number);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}

String value = "0.00";
private String getCurrentPrice() {
    value = "0.00";
    String url = "https://www.mywebservice.net/stock/";
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String data= new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                JSONObject res = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONObject obj = res.getJSONObject("values");
                String last = obj.getString("stock");
                value = last;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.d("STK", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return String.format("USD %.2f",Double.parseDouble(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> return String.format("USD %.2f",Double.parseDouble(value));

Because `client.get()` is an async call, it immediately executes and moves on to the return statement. That is why you see no change because the `value` is still 0. Put the return inside `onSuccess()`. You also need to return a value from `onFailure()`.

**Edit**

Since onSuccess is void, you need to pass in a callback which will be called after the parsing.

```
interface ResponseCallback {
     void success(String value);
}
```

Then,

```
getCurrentPrice(new ResponseCallback() {
     @Override
     void success(String value) {
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, value);
     }
}
```

Inside getCurrentPrice (don't return the value) -

```
private void getCurrentPrice(ResponseCallback callback) {
    ...
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
              try {
                  ...
                  String last = obj.getString("stock");
                  callback.success(last);
              } catch(...)
          }
```

Comment: onSuccess() is void, cann't retun a String

Comment: @user1801745 Sorry, yes you need to implement a callback. Check the updated answer.

Comment: still not working, a change loopj for AsyncTask class and works on my device, not in emulator (D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 366K, 5% free 10713K/11207K, paused 5ms+30ms V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 183 from 121 (151%)) Seems like to much process for a widget...!?